# Is it grammatically correct to use 'carry out' in this context?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to use 'carry out' in this context?

> I carry out the regeneration and production of machinery parts in the
>   food sector.

Comment: It's "grammatically" correct, but idiomatically an extremely unlikely sentence. More natural would be *"I make and repair machinery used in the food industry"*. We *carry out **tasks*** (not ***activities***), and the emphasis is on *successful completion* (not *repetition*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the use of "carry out" is grammatically correct in this context.